# Image crop from both sides and stay center

Tags: html, css

Basically I have a somewhat footer image what is browser width and when I decrease the browser width it starts to crop from the right side.

What I want is it to stay center and crop from both sides?

```
<footer class="site-footer">
  <img class="footer-bg" src="assets/img/footer-bg.png" alt="">
</footer>
```

```css
.site-footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.site-footer .footer-bg {
   /* Set rules to fill background */
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 1024px;
   /* Set up proportionate scaling */
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
  background-position: no-repeat fixed center top;
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Crop sides of image to size of screen and center align it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602585/crop-sides-of-image-to-size-of-screen-and-center-align-it)

Comment: doesnt seem work with my example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can achieve this with background-image property.

http://codepen.io/asim-coder/pen/YywaeB

HTML:

```
<footer class="site-footer">
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
.site-footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/500/60);
  height: 60px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I suppose thats the best way - I for some reason fixated on the <img> tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .site-footer .footer-bg {
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 1024px;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   background-position: no-repeat fixed center top;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
  }
```

OR

You should use background-image to set it.

This will allow you to center it easily like so:

```
body{
 background: url("path/to/image") no-repeat fixed center top; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this (if you need the `<img>` tag, otherwise use background):

```
.site-footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.site-footer .footer-bg {
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 1024px;
   width: auto;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   transform: translateX(-50%);
   -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%); /** for iOS **/
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 solutions:

1. Get another approach to set footer background using CSS background-image instead of `<img>` element. Important is that if `position:absolute` , you need to set both `width` and `height` of `<footer>`:

```html
<footer class="site-footer"></footer>
    
    .site-footer {   
       position: absolute;   
       right: 0;      
       bottom: 0;   
       left: 0;   
       text-align: center;   
       overflow: hidden;   
       width: ?? ;   
       height: ??;   
       background:url(assets/img/footer-bg.png) 0 0 no-repeat);   
       background-size:100%;   
    }
```

2. If you still need/must use `<img>` element, try code below (still need to setup `<footer> hight` and `width` and  float img to left.)

```html
.site-footer {
      position: absolute;
      min-width: 1024px;
      width: ??;
      height: ??;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      text-align: center;
      overflow: hidden;  
    }
    .site-footer .footer-bg {
       float:left;
       /* Set rules to fill background */
       min-height: 100%;
       min-width: 1024px;
       /* Set up proportionate scaling */
       width: 100%;
       height: auto;
     }
```

Comment: Sorry, it took me a while to style it properly. If you take a closer look, it all make sense ;)